# How to override = operator in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there any way to override or overload `=` operator inside a class in Scala to implicitly converting data without defining implicit methods?

for example :

```
class A{
    def =(str:String)={
       .........
    }
}
.........
val a=new A
a="TEST"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Scala Language Specification, section 1.1, `=` is a reserved word. You can't, therefore, override or overload it.

Answer (score 6):

You can't override `=` in Scala because it is a language defined operator (like `(`, `[` or `<-` are).

The only thing you can do is to use the update-method:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A {
  var data = Map.empty[Int, String]
  def update(i: Int, str: String) {
    data += i -> str
  }
  def apply(i: Int): String =
    data(i)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A

scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@77cb05b9

scala> a(5) = "hello"

scala> a(5)
res7: String = hello
```

But it is still not possible to leave out the parentheses in `a(5) = "hello"` because `a = "hello"` is the syntax to redefine a value. The shortest possible notation is `a() = "hello"`, when you only specify the update-method like this: `def update(str: String) {...}`

See [this blog post](http://daily-scala.blogspot.de/2009/08/apply-update-methods.html) for a more detailed explanation on how to use the update-method.

Comment: It makes your class to act like a map, but my I need converting the given data to the object

Comment: @Pooya: That is not clear from your question. Can you clarify a bit more what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to know, Can I override `=` operator to assign another type to my object without defining `implicit def toA(str:String):A={....}` method?

Comment: @Pooya : maybe knowing **why** you want to do this will allow us to answer your question? Specifically, what's wrong with implicits that you want to avoid them?

Comment: For example I have this type `class ResourceMap extends mutable.HashMap[String, Int]{ ..... }`. I want to assign this string "foor*10,wood*20" to the instantiated object of the class

Comment: @Pooya : "assign... to the object"? So do you want to replace the key->val bindings without replacing the instance reference?

Comment: No, It is implicit conversion of a type to another type

Comment: @Pooya : so, a new instance then, after all. Alright, then **why** don't you want to use an implicit method? Please edit in this info to your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37782/discussion-between-pooya-and-theterribleswifttomato)

Comment: You don't need an `apply` method, and you could create `update` method with a single parameter. This works as expected: `class Test { def update(s: String) = println(s) }; val a = new Test; a() = "x"`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Scala-Virtualized](https://github.com/TiarkRompf/scala-virtualized/wiki/Virtualized-Scala-Reference), where you can override all control structures. This is nearly certainly overkill, but the option exists.

Comment: +1, nice piece of info, although I agree that this is overkill.